# Undefined variable, using laravel 7, can't defind parametes for route, CRUD using eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel

i want to making a CRUD in laravel 7 using eloquent ORM without ajax, and this is my update controller for crud `AdmindataController.php`

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'id_jadwal' => 'required',
        'hari' => 'required',
        'jam_masuk' => 'required',
        'jam_keluar' => 'required',
    ]);

    // $schedule->update($request->all());

    $jad = Schedule::find($id);

    $jad->id_jadwal = $request->get('id_jadwal');
    $jad->hari = $request->get('hari');
    $jad->jam_masuk = $request->get('jam_masuk');
    $jad->jam_keluar = $request->get('jam_keluar');
    $jad->save();

    return redirect()->route('data.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');
}
```

and then, i have registered my route as follows in `web.php`

```
Route::resource('admin/data', 'AdmindataController');
```

and when i run `php artisan route:list` in my composer is show this:

[image]

```
 PUT|PATCH | admin/data/{data}      | data.update   | App\Http\Controllers\AdmindataController@update
```

this is my base view `datajadwal.blade.php` i'm using this to view my table data which is there is an edit, add, and delete button.

```
    foreach($data as $jadwal)
                  <tr>
                    <th scope='row'><div align="center">{{$loop->iteration}}</div></th>
                    <td><div align="center">{{$jadwal->id_jadwal}}</div></td>
                    <td><div align="center">{{$jadwal->hari}}</div></td>
                    <td><div align="center">{{$jadwal->jam_masuk}}</div></td>
                    <td><div align="center">{{$jadwal->jam_keluar}}</div></td>
                    <td><div align="center">
                      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editjadwal-{{ $jadwal->id }}" class="btn btn-success">edit</a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a> 
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
      @endforeach
```

and also i'm using a modal to show my form modal (editform, addform, deleteform). and this is my edit modal

```
@foreach ($data as $edit)
<div class="modal fade" id="editjadwal-{{ $edit->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
@endforeach
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-info" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Form</h5>
      <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('data.update', $jad->id) }}">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    
    <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ID Jadwal</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="updateidjadwal" id="id_jadwal"
                placeholder="Masukkan ID Jadwal" value="{{$jad->updateidjadwal}}">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Update Data </button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i've made a store function and it worked well, but when i used update function to edit my data, parameter variable `$jad` is undefined when it was defined in my updated function.

and my eror is always on `<form method="post" action="{{ route('data.update', $jad->id) }}">` i've tried any references to solve this but i'm always stuck on this issue . And the last error when i running this project is

```
ErrorException Undefined variable:jad (View:D:\Aplikasi\laragon\www\tugasakhir\resources\views\includes\modal\editjadwal.blade.php)http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/data
```

where am i doing wrong and what would be the correct fix?
i'm so confused, i hope somebody can answer my questions.

Comment: why are you using Schedule?

Comment: Your route param is `{data}`, do your function param will be `$data` instead of `$id`

Comment: and where is `$jad` supposed to come from?